# Static files not serving when uploaded in Google app engine (SDK Go)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I was trying to use google app engine cloud space. My program is running without any problem in localhost, but when I tries to host it in google app engine, static files are not served. The app.yaml is as follows:

```
application: myTestApp-nn34322
version: 1
runtime: go
threadsafe: true
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /static/css
  static_dir: ../static/css
  mime_type: "text/css"

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: ../static/js
  mime_type: "text/javascript"

- url: /static/images
  static_dir: ../static/images

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Comment: Do you get `HTTP 404` error when attempting to get the static files? Also, are `app.yaml` and the `static` folder in the same folder?

Comment: Yes I am getting 404. I am using beegae framework. so my app.yaml is in main folder. and my static folder is in root along with main folder.

Comment: My feeling is that your `static` folder doesn't get uploaded to Appengine. Try to move the `static` folder next to `app.yaml`, and of course use: `static_dir: static/xxx`.

Comment: @icza Thanks man. it worked. It would be great if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put every static resources under the same folder where you put your `app.yaml` file, else they won't get uploaded to AppEngine.

So you should put your `static` folder next to `app.yaml`, and then of course the correct path is simply `static/xxx`, e.g.:

```
- url: /static/css
  static_dir: static/css
  mime_type: "text/css"

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: static/js
  mime_type: "text/javascript"

- url: /static/images
  static_dir: static/images
```

**Note:**

If you intend to use these static files from your Go app too (e.g. you want to read their content), that requires special handling because resources matched by static file patterns will not be copied to the application after uploading (static files are served by separate servers). For details, see [Google App Engine Golang no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285670/google-app-engine-golang-no-such-file-or-directory/29288854#29288854). Basically you either have to duplicate the static files, or provide the `application_readable` option to the static file handler.